# Jenkins exclude regions (Git) not working

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to set up my Jenkins project so that whenever I push README.md, it won't trigger a build. This is what I have set up:

[image]

But it doesn't work. Whenever I do a push, it builds anyway. Am I doing something wrong here?

EDIT: I should clarify that it actually works fine if I just edit README.md, and push the branch. But if I edit README.md on say, master, then merge that change into develop and push develop, it triggers a build.

Comment: Possibly related to this Jenkins bug: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23606 - the bug report is for included regions, but it might be the same for excluded regions.

Comment: Wow, a year-old bug! :( Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My fix for this is :

1. Put path relative to GIT_ROOT.
2. Append a cap ^ before the path in include/exclude regions.
   Example : `^pollme/.*` where pollme is the first folder under git repo heirarchy.
3. Enable  "Force polling using workspace" under Additional Behaviors in git plugin in jenkins.

Works perfectly for me after applying above options.

Comment: Where did you put this GIT_ROOT config?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

1. You need to use a external git configuration tool on "Global Configuration Tool" like this (You need to have this installed on the server):
   [image]
2. Configure your project to use this Git setted above on "Source Code Management":
   [image]